# retriving and accessing identical elements in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I am automating tests for a WebApp with Selenium in Java. One of the test cases has to use a slider with 2 points on it (for choosing an age range)

[image: slider to automate]

In the HTML-code both points are represented by

[image: html code of the two elements]

The style-attribute `left:` changes accordingly to the position of the point on the slider bar.

**Now to the problem I am facing:**

I cannot get a hold on both of those slider-elements at the same time. I have tried:

- PageFactory with `@FindAll`, both css selectors and xpath:

  ```
  @FindAll({
    @FindBy(xpath = "//slider/span")
  })
  private List<WebElement> ageSliders;
  ```
- `driver.findBy(...)` with css and xpath selectors - globally and locally in the method, just in case there are any problems with the PageFactory element initialisation
- getting the parent element and iterating through the children to get to the slider points
- some other combinations of the above

Whatever I do however, retrieves only one element twice. For example doing:

```
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//slider/span[@class='pointer'][1]")))
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//slider/span[@class='pointer'][2]")))
```

prints out two elements with the same id:

```
[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on MAC (ee9fc3d7-77fb-3042-9002-5316c1d94e89)] -> xpath: //slider/span[@class='pointer'][1]]
[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on MAC (ee9fc3d7-77fb-3042-9002-5316c1d94e89)] -> xpath: //slider/span[@class='pointer'][2]]
```

Which makes accessing both of them separately impossible. Sliding both elements moves only the left one.

The same happens while iterating through the `ageSliders` list from above: I always seem to get only the left slider (= the first one in the DOM?).

The only time I was able to operate the right slider was, when I accessed only it, i.e. without trying to touch the other one:

```
@FindAll({
  @FindBy(xpath = "//slider/span")
})
private List<WebElement> ageSliders;

(...)

resetSlider(ageSliders.get(1))
```

However doing for example

```
resetSlider(ageSliders.get(1))
resetSlider(ageSliders.get(0))
```

in the above example moves just the left slider again... very confusing o_O

I would be grateful for any tips or experiences, which would help me solve this issue.

Comment: I have found a workaround for the time being:
slide the left slider,
refresh the page,
slide the right slider. It's not a real solution though :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried an experiment with the following HTML:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <slider>
            <span class="pointer" style="left: 58.878px"></span>
            <span class="pointer" style="left: 187.024px"></span>
        </slider>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then I ran the following simple test code:

```
public class FooTest {

    @Test
    public void foo() {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        FooPage page = new FooPage();
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, page);
        driver.get("file:///Users/aarondavis/Desktop/index.html");
        for (WebElement elem : page.getPointers()) {
            System.out.println(elem);
            System.out.println(elem.getAttribute("style"));
        }
        driver.quit();
    }

    public static final class FooPage {
        @FindBy(xpath = "//slider/span")
        private List<WebElement> pointers;

        public List<WebElement> getPointers() {
            return pointers;
        }
    }
}
```

The output shows both elements being iterated over:

```
[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on MAC (fdbc9c63-a173-d44b-97be-c328210ce0bf)] -> xpath: //slider/span]
left: 58.878px;
[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on MAC (fdbc9c63-a173-d44b-97be-c328210ce0bf)] -> xpath: //slider/span]
left: 187.024px;
```

What is the code you are using to move the slider (e.g. the body of the `resetSlider` method)? My guess is either there's an issue in that method or that there are other elements on the page that match `//slider/span` that might be being retrieved. You can check that by simply printing the size of the list (e.g. `System.out.println(page.getPointers.size());`). Another possibility is if there is validation of the sliders on the page side (e.g. you can't move the right one to the left of the left one and/or they have to be a certain distance, etc).

Note: BTW the output you posted above doesn't show the same id ... this sort of toString:

```
[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on MAC (fdbc9c63-a173-d44b-97be-c328210ce0bf)] -> xpath: //slider/span]
```

is simply the web element toString. That long dash-separated string is not an id of the element but rather of the web driver. Also please note you don't need to use a `@FindAll...` to get a list of elements. That is for a different semantic case. Whether or not you get a list of elements with a `@FindBy` in a page object is determined simply by if the field it is annotating is declared as a type of `WebElement` or a `List<WebElement>`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried few more things, but the effects are still very inconsistent. Sometimes I can slide both sliders, sometimes only one. Will talk to people, who build it in the first place, and hope they can provide some explanation.

Also thanks for pointing out, that the long string in a WebElement's toString is in fact the WebDriver ID, don't know how I missed that until now :)